# How to remove & nbsp; from dom that don't appear in text editor (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've noticed on rendered pages of my Wordpress website, lines of text breaking in places where there's no html code directing to do so. Particularly on mobiles.

Looking at the DOM I can see instances of & nbsp; which don't appear in the Wordpress text editor. One page, which I pasted in from another Wordpress instance, is particularly full of them, but it's not limited to that page.

I'm trying to fix this issue so that none of my pages or posts have & nbsp; in the dom when it's not in the source code.

I've tried:

- Copying all the html code into notepad and pasting back into Wordpress. Didn't work.
- Copying all the text in the visual tab and then switching on the 'paste as text' mode and pasting it all back in, paragraph for paragraph. Didn't work either.

Here's an example of the DOM

```
<p>I think I should probably qualify that statement before all the bass experts&nbsp;point out how difficult many bass lines are. The bass is an easy instrument to&nbsp;learn&nbsp;if&nbsp;you stick&nbsp;with&nbsp;simple bass lines.&nbsp;Now,&nbsp;as luck would have it,&nbsp;rock music is full of&nbsp;famous&nbsp;songs with easy bass lines.</p>
```

And here's the relative source code:

```
<p>I think I should probably qualify that statement before all the bass experts point out how difficult many bass lines are. The bass is an easy instrument to learn if you stick with simple bass lines. Now, as luck would have it, rock music is full of famous songs with easy bass lines.</p>
```

The expected result is not to have & nbsp; in the dom if it's not in the source code.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code for your template and your posts, but my guess is that either the visual editor or the template add these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this one ended up being simple.

The issue was characters from MS Word that didn't show up in Wordpress text editor or Notepad and weren't stripped out when I moved the text to Notepad and back, or when I copied the text and pasted back into Wordpress with the 'paste as text' switched on.

How I handled this was to paste the html code into MS Word, go to options and then switch on showing all formatting. I was then able to see the characters causing this issue. So I copied the character and did a find and replace in the whole document for a space character.

This has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try disable all plugins + go back to the default template. If this solves the issue, start enabling template and plugins one by one until issue occurs again to find what is causing this.